# How to put integer bits in a float?

Tags: c++

I have vertices coming in as float_3's. I want to add an integer to them and then ship them out as float_4's. I don't want to convert the integer into a float with the same value, I need the bits to be exactly the same (the integer is a bucket xyz value bit shifted together).

Here is what I tried:

```
void tagVerts (vector<float_3> &Verts, vector<float_4> &Output) {
    int len = Verts.size();
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        Output[i].xyz = Verts[i];
        Output[i].w = reinterpret_cast<float>(XYZTag(Verts[i]));
    }
}
```

it says invalid type conversion :/

EDIT:
float_3 and float_4 are from amp.h, as far as I can tell they are just 3 or 4 floats in a struct with a bunch of conversion and assignment helper functions.

XYZTag is as follows:

```
int XYZTag(float_3 pos) {
    pos = pos * mul + add;
    int_3 posi (static_cast<int>(pos.x), static_cast<int>(pos.y), static_cast<int>(pos.z));
    return((posi.x << 10) + posi.y << 10) + posi.z;
}
```

Comment: How are `float_3`, `float_4`, and `XYZTag` defined?

Comment: You can't `reinterpret_cast<float>(an_int)` - use `static_cast<float>(an_int)`, or leave the cast out completely and the compiler will do it implicitly.

Comment: but that just gets the value, which is bound to get mangled up with bigger numbers, i need the exact bits so i can do the inverse once they get to the destination.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must not interpret the bits of an `int` as a `float` as doing so would violate [strict aliasing rules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/98650/what-is-the-strict-aliasing-rule) and therefore invoke undefined behavior.  The correct way to do this is to copy the bits over using `memcpy`.

```
#include <cstring>

inline float
int_bits_to_float(const int bits)
{
  static_assert(sizeof(int) >= sizeof(float), "too few bits");
  float target;
  std::memcpy(&target, &bits, sizeof(float));
  return target;
}
```

As terrible a solution as it might seem to be at a first glance, we should really expect the compiler to figure out that this can be optimized down to a few move instructions.  GCC does this even at default optimization level.

Answer (score 0):

`reinterpret_cast` will not reinterpret an `int` as a `float`, but it can reinterpret **a pointer**.

```
int temp = XYZTag(Verts[i]);
Output[i].w = *reinterpret_cast<float*>(&temp);
//            ^                      ^  ^
```

This will stuff the exact bits of your `int` into the `float Output[i].w`.   It will be your responsibility to ensure that those types are the same size.

Comment: doesn't work directly in vs2012, the compiler demands a lvalue

Comment: This is breaking strict aliasing rules even if `sizeof(int) == sizeof(float)`.

Comment: `reinterpret_cast<float&>` is shorter.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot `reinterpret_cast<>` the `int` directly. The `static_cast<>` will not do what you want.

To copy the bit pattern to another type, you need something like:

```
int val = 23;
float bitCopy = *reinterpret_cast<float*>(&val);
```

Now, for this to work at all, you better have `sizeof(float)` and `sizeof(int)` the same.

Further, we'll have to assume you know what you are doing to want this at all.